# Group IE tabs into one taskbar icon?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I like that in Chrome, no matter how many tabs you have open, there is only 1 singular icon on the taskbar. Naturally, IE displays an icon per tab open instead. Is there a way to change this on Windodws 7 / IE9?

I came across this SU posted: [Force IE to use one process per tab](https://superuser.com/questions/586622/force-ie-to-use-one-process-per-tab)

But it didn't seem to do what I wanted. Not sure if it's actually relevant or I just misunderstood it and thought it was relevant.

Comment: "IE displays an icon per tab open instead" - No...It doesn't....If it does then you have enabled that [option](http://superuser.com/questions/131146/prevent-internet-explorer-tabs-from-opening-tabs-in-stack-in-taskbar?rq=1).

Comment: @Ramhound: IE11 by default shows only one taskbar button *per window* (regardless of number of tabs in each window), just like Firefox does. I haven't tested with IE9 but IIRC it was no different. Perhaps the OP just needs to reset IE.

Answer (score 9):

You should just enable behavior that accomplishes what you want.

Internet Options -> Tabs

[image]

Then enable the option:

[image]

Comment: I dont think someone can help you better than this.

Comment: Someone doesn't get what is required by following this method doesn't make this answer invalid. There was no point in the downvote. I support.

Comment: @Ramhound: Abandoned posts and spurious downvotes are a fact of life. Been there, had that. Do not take it personally.

Comment: @Ramhound: Lots of question askers fail to accept answers even when they've themselves indicated that particular answers helped. In this case I think there's just an issue with the OP's setup, so this is hardly a great generic question that might help others. No-one has been able to replicate multiple taskbar buttons per window for IE.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the solution is actually pretty simple.

In IE, open `Internet Options` and click the `Tabs` button. **Uncheck** the `Show Previews for individual tabs in the taskbar` checkbox.

Restart IE and then you will only have one taskbar icon - the same behaviour as chrome

Comment: Only one taskbar icon, but also the preview of only one tab.

Comment: That just changes the number of thumbnail previews, not the number of buttons shown on the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question by @Ramhound about his answer not being accepted,
I have attempted to verify it by recreating the situation as reported
by the poster. But I was unable to cause IE to display
a separate taskbar icon per tab.

What I have tried :

- Unchecking the Internet Options entry of "Enable tab groups"
- Executing the [registry tweak](https://superuser.com/questions/586622/force-ie-to-use-one-process-per-tab) described by the poster
- Setting the taskbar to "Never combine".

I have rebooted after each change, but have never managed to have multiple
taskbar icons for one IE instance.

I must therefore assume one of the following :

1. The poster has launched multiple instances of IE when the taskbar was set to
   "Never combine" and wrongly expected their icons to be combined, or
2. The poster has changed some other setting in Windows but has no idea what he did that caused this problem.

The second case is identical in effect to having a corrupted version of Windows.
If the poster cannot remember what he did, the only solutions are [Repair Installation](https://superuser.com/questions/586622/force-ie-to-use-one-process-per-tab), or if this doesn't help, the re-installation of Windows.
But this seems to me like really too much trouble for such a small problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the poster was asking about removing the preview thumbnails for each tab which pop up when you click on or hover over the grouped taskbar icon. That's what I was trying to figure out when I got here. I don't recollect if Windows 7 does that as I've been on Win10 for quite a while now.

Using IE11 on Win10:

- Open **Internet Options**
- Click the **Tabs** button
- Uncheck the **Show previews for individual tabs in the taskbar*** entry

Answer (score 0):

I am using IE11 in Windows Home premium.
I wanted only one icon on the task  bar, the shortcut for IE11 and any corresponding icons for open windows combined into this icon. This was achieved by creating a shortcut on the desktop then dragging that to the task bar. 
Now when I open IE11 the icon does not move but shows that I have more than one window open. Hovering the mouse, (if using aero) gives a preview of all the open windows.